# Not a managed type. Spring Boot Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

Preface: I've been looking for the solution to this answer for months, and have looked at *all* the answers on SO regarding this, but am yet to find a solution. These errors *only occur on the update from Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE to SB 2+.*

## Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [/Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/server/lp-server-deploy/out/production/classes/com/company/app/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantDataService' defined in file [/Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/server/lp-server-read/out/production/classes/com/company/app/projection/applicant/service/ApplicantDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantViewRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:676)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:235)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:188)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [/Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/server/lp-server-deploy/out/production/classes/com/company/app/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantDataService' defined in file [/Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/server/lp-server-read/out/production/classes/com/company/app/projection/applicant/service/ApplicantDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantViewRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:668)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [/Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/server/lp-server-deploy/out/production/classes/com/company/app/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantDataService' defined in file [/Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/server/lp-server-read/out/production/classes/com/company/app/projection/applicant/service/ApplicantDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantViewRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:590)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:138)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:54)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:390)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantDataService' defined in file [/Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/server/lp-server-read/out/production/classes/com/company/app/projection/applicant/service/ApplicantDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantViewRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantViewRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:150)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 141 more
```

## Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = IntegrationTestActiveProfileResolver::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [IntegrationTestApplicationConfiguration::class])
class FixTest {
    @Test
    fun `Check that configuration is loaded correctly`() {
        assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

## IntegrationTestApplicationConfiguration

```
@AutoConfigurationPackage
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {
                "com.company.common.spring.spring2",
                "com.company.common.spring.spring2.config",
                "com.company.decisioning",
                "com.company.factory",
                "com.company.app",
                "com.company.app.config",
                "com.company.lp",
                "com.company.mapping"
        },
        includeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = { TokenHandler.class })
        },
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class),
        }
)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {
                "com.company.app",
                "com.company.factory",
                "com.company.decisioning",
                "com.company.mapping",
                "com.company.app.document.mapping",
                "com.company.app.common",
                "com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel",
        },
        transactionManagerRef = "dictionaryJpaTransactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "dictionaryEntityManagerFactory"
)
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
        "com.datapublica.pg.types",
        "com.company.app",
        "com.company.factory",
        "com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel",
        "org.axonframework.eventhandling.saga.repository.jpa",
        "org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.jpa",
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class IntegrationTestApplicationConfiguration {}
```

Let's start with the obvious. It seems weird that I need to have a `transactionManagerRef` and `entityManagerFactoryRef` specified in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` block, but if I remove those then the error changes to be

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.mapping.VendorMap
```

which is super strange to me. I don't understand why I need to specify these refs, as they should be picked up by the component scan.

But the problem is, is that something is still terribly wrong. I can't get past the `Not a managed type: class com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao` error, even if I add in the appropriate scans. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong...

Any explanation of how the scanning is working here would be fantastic.

I'm guessing it has to do with the exclusion of all autoconfiguration classes, but I don't know how to exclude all autoconfiguration classes except a few. If we configure all the autoconfiguration classes, we have the tests break in entirely different ways.

edit: [here is a repository containing a spring boot app, with a library alongside it (gradle composite build)](https://github.com/snowe2010/so-55975868). You'll also need to build https://github.com/datapublica/hibernate-pg-json and push to your mavenLocal.

Comment: For starters stop including Spring Data yourself, but rather use the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` to get a tested Spring Data dependency. You seem to try very hard to bypass the versions managed by Spring Boot. Next to that why do you have a seperate configuration for your test, rather then use the normal `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: Because this is an enterprise app and we need the configuration. This isn't some starter app where you only need the most simple of things.

Answer (score 1):

Project setup is broken. Minimal example is not that minimal and riddled with dependency conflicts. Project also uses unsupported dependency management mechanism `implementation(platform(<spring-boot-dependencies>))`. It's hard to debug an issue because of all of this. Maybe after all conflicts and dependency management issues are resolved the issue from the question will also disappear :)

Comment: I think you might have missed the error. It's complaining about `com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao` which is being scanned in the `@EntityScan`

Comment: though just to make sure I'm not a moron, I still added the package to the entityscan and it still responds with the same message.

Comment: Oh, I thought the error you were asking about was `"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.mapping.VendorMap"`

Comment: I guess that question is part of the overall question. Why does adding those two ref factories cause `Not a managed type: class com.company.mapping.VendorMap` to go away, but then allow the second message `Not a managed type: class com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao` through?

Comment: A lot is going on here, it is hard to diagnose without looking at the full setup and classes, but things to check would be: conflicting stuff 1) since you need to specify transactionManager and entityManagerFactory, I guess you have more than one option of each in the scanned packages; 2) don't list both `a.b` and `a.b.c` in the basePackages, scanning is recursive.

Comment: I've reread your configuration more carefully and I see that you do not enable auto-configuration, which is probably the reason you need to specify all of these scans and refs (that is unless your application structure is such that you cannot use `@EnableAutoConfiguration`)

Comment: We are explicitly disabling autoconfiguration with the `excludeFilters`, and just as well, we also cannot use the plain scans because we have two package roots `com.company.factory` and `com.company.app`. And yes the scanning is recursive, _but it sometimes doesn't work unless I specify the nested package!!!!_ I really don't understand.

Comment: Could you please provide a repro project? Otherwise it is very hard to help.

Comment: I will work on creating a repro project. I've tried before and failed, but I'm at an impasse so I'll have to figure it out somehow.

Comment: please provide MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it would be a great help

Comment: Ok, it only took 10 days, but I edited my post above with an SSCCE and added a bit of information about what else is needed. Sorry for the massive delay, it was quite difficult to get it down from hundreds of thousands of lines to this.

Answer (score 1):

One option I can suggest you is to try annotating your entity classes that are used inside *com.company.app.common.applicant.viewmodel.ApplicantViewDao* class with **@Entity** annotation.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Annotate the View and Id classes?

Comment: Domain classes should be annotated with @Entity. Try to annotate ApplicationViewDao class with it

Comment: It already has that annotation. You can see the attached example project to see where the annotation is.